# Can I use AllJoyn Framework for Wifi Direct in iOS?

Tags: ios, wifi-direct, alljoyn

I want to develop an iOS application through which I have to communicate with other devices(other than iOS devices) over WiFi direct.

As per my knowledge there are no APIs provided in iOS for WiFi direct communication.

I found a link regarding third party library AllJoyn.
[AllJoyn Framework](https://allseenalliance.org/framework)

Has anybody used this library for iOS?

Is AllJoyn provide a good support if in future developer faces any issue with this library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a past contributor to the iOS bindings of AllJoyn.

AllJoyn does not currently support Wifi Direct for iOS.

However, you can accomplish peer-to-peer communication using AllJoyn if you are on the same wifi network. This will certainly depend on your use case but you can accomplish a lot without having the need to use Wifi direct.

Wifi direct can be tricky in your case since you are trying to communicate with devices other than iOS from an iOS device. The interoperability with depend in how iOS and other OSes (for e.g Android) would implement it.

From my past experiments, having even Android devices talk over Wifi direct highlighted issues that were because of how certain manufacturers implemented it even though it is supposed to be standardized soon.

AllJoyn is an open source framework with a list of active developers working towards maintaining it. You can subscribe to their [core mailing list](https://lists.allseenalliance.org/mailman/listinfo/allseen-core) to get your questions answered and as with any open source project they have an active bug tracking system [(Jira)](https://jira.allseenalliance.org/browse/ASACORE/component/10007/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:component-summary-panel). This is a good way to find out how the framework is doing in terms of supporting developers/users of the framework.

Comment: Thank you very much NikofTime for your answer. Can you please guide me, what are some other ways by which iOS device can communicate with other iOS or non iOS devices?

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you were looking for Wifi direct? If the goal is communication between iOS and non-iOS device without the presence of internet connection then AllJoyn will suffice.
However, a lot of frameworks will use a cloud based approach which will require an internet connection. 
You can also look at Bluetooth LE if you aren't looking to stream/transferring a lot of data. Both iOS and Android offer BLE APIs

Comment: If you found my answer about AllJoyn, Wifi direct and peer-to-peer address your question please accept my answer. It helps others