# Is any specific code required to use Wifi Direct in AllJoyn on Android?

Tags: android, wifi-direct, alljoyn

I've tried running AllJoyn's sample chat app on Android, with two phones connected over Wifi-Direct, but the two chat apps don't see each other.  Is any special code required to make use of Wifi-Direct in AllJoyn?

A secondary question is whether Wifi-Direct is even supported on AllJoyn?  I've seen several postings indicating Wifi-Direct support as been removed, but those postings are over 2 years old, and the AllJoyn web site still seems to indicate support for Wifi-Direct.  Does anyone have up-to-date knowledge of this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540495/can-i-use-alljoyn-framework-for-wifi-direct-in-ios

Comment: It looks like it isn't supported, that post is relatively recent from around 8 months ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WiFi Direct (wifi p2p) is not currently supported in AllJoyn.

Looking at the AllJoyn Standard Code repository (https://cgit.allseenalliance.org/core/alljoyn.git), you will see that there had been code for it back in the 14.12 release (RB14.12 branch December 2014), but was deprecated. And was removed by the 15.04 release (RB15.04 branch April 2015).